# Concatenate two columns in google sheets script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to concatenate two columns delimited by `,` and post back the results to a third column
 Data looks like:

```
colA     colb      concatenated
aa bb    ww ww     aa bb, ww ww
mm
         qq        qq
zz oo              zz oo

ss       vv zz     ss, vv zz
```

I get the error `Cannot read property "0" from undefined.`

Thanks for any help

```
function ConCat() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Elements");
    var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
    var values1 = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lr,1).getValues();  //Get vales for Column1
    var values2 = sheet.getRange(1, 2, lr,1).getValues();  //Get values for column 2
    var results = [];                               //Create a empty array to be filled concatenated elements

    //Add items to results
    for(var i=0; i<lr; i++){
        results[i] = (values1[i][0]+", "+values2[i][0]);
    }

    //Post back to column 3 starting on row 2
    sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues([results]);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

setValues wants a 2d array. You have a 1d array. Change

results[i] = (values1[i][0]+", "+values2[i][0]); to

```
results[i] = [values1[i][0]+", "+values2[i][0]];
```

and change

sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues([results]); to

```
sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues(results);
```

Comment: Ed, thank you that did the trick.  I now have a bunch of cells that look like this `, aa` or `bb, ` or just `, ` I would like all the leading or trailing or just `, ` to be removed but I will ask this in a new question.  Thanks again

Comment: The way it is written, the first row is also taken and combined and therefore it shifts the entire array one row down.

sheet.getRange(2, 3, lr, 1).setValues(results);

should be:

sheet.getRange(1, 3, lr, 1).setValues(results);

Which will;l add the array in column 3, but the first town, instead of second.

Answer (score 0):

try this:
results.addItem(values[i][0]+' '+values[i][1]);
or
results.push(values[i][0],values[i][1]);

Comment: Hello Sree Kumar, thanks for the response, I get the error ` Cannot find function addItem in object `

Comment: Scree thanks again, I tried `results.push(values[i][0],values[i][1]);` and now I get the error `Incorrect range height, was 1 but should be 190 ` getting tere